# Getting a user ID

Tags: java, performance, beginner

I have a method to query different users according to type and return `userId`. But there are too many switch-cases. Can someone give me some advice?

```
private Optional<Integer> getId(int type, String appId, String openId) {

    Integer id = null;
    switch (type) {

        case 1:
            Type1User type1User = userRepository.getType1User(openId);
            validateUserNotNull(type1User);
            id = type1User.getId();
            break;
        case 2:
            Type2User type2User = userRepository.getType2User(openId);
            validateUserNotNull(type2User);
            id = type2User.getId();
            break;
        case 4:
            Type4User type4User = userRepository.getType4UserByOpenId(openId);
            validateUserNotNull(type4User);
            id = type4User.getId();
            break;
        case 5:
            Type5User type5User = userRepository.getType5UserByOpenId(openId);
            validateUserNotNull(type5User);
            id = type5User.getId();
            break;
        case 6:
            Type6User type6User = userRepository.getType6UserByOpenId(openId);
            validateUserNotNull(type6User);
            id = type6User.getId();
            break;
        case 8:
            Type8User type8User = userRepository.getType8User(Long.valueOf(openId));
            validateUserNotNull(type8User);
            id = type8User.getId();
            break;
        case 11:
            Type11User type11User = userRepository.getType11UserByTokenAndUID(appId, openId);
            validateUserNotNull(type11User);
            id = type11User.getId();
            break;
        case 12:
            Type12User type12User = userRepository.getType12UserByAppIdAndOpenId(appId, openId);
            validateUserNotNull(type12User);
            id = type12User.getId();
            break;
        case 13:
            Type13User type13User = userRepository.getType13UserByAppIdAndOpenId(appId, openId);
            validateUserNotNull(type13User);
            id = type13User.getId();
        default:
            break;
    }
    return Optional.ofNullable(id);
}

private void validateUserNotNull(Object user) {

    if (user == null) {
        throw new UserNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more context for this code. What do the `userRepository` methods look like? What's the difference between all the types of users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You should replace conditional with Polymorphism.](https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism)

Make separate classes for each UserType that implements a common interface or abstract class, and pass objects of those classes instead of passing `type` as method arguments.

Comment: Usually I't support that. But what the OP shows is a *factory method* and this is the only place in a code base where we cannot avoid branching. This is because it is the necessary preparation to enable  *replace conditional with Polymorphism* in the rest of the code.

Comment: I agree with you @TimothyTruckle, but I use a different approach for a factory. I usually create a hashmap with ID/type as key and a `Supplier` as value.

Comment: "hiding" the branching behind a map is a valid way to go...

Answer (score 1):

This is a *factory method* Therefor you cannot avoid branching here.

But you can reduce *code duplication*.

As suggested by [Ankit Soni](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/198213/121225) you should have an *interface* that all your different user classes implement:

```
interface TypeUser{
  Integer getId();
}

class TypeUser1 implements TypeUser {
   private final Integer id;
   @Override
   public Integer getId(){
      return id;
   }
  // ...
}
```

Then in your method you could store all different UserType-objects in a variable of same type having the same name:

```
Integer id = null;
switch (type) {
    case 1:
        TypeUser typeUser = userRepository.getType1User(openId);
        validateUserNotNull(typeUser);
        id = typeUser.getId();
        break;
    case 2:
        TypeUser typeUser = userRepository.getType2User(openId);
        validateUserNotNull(typeUser);
        id = typeUser.getId();
        break;
    case 4:
        TypeUser typeUser = userRepository.getType4UserByOpenId(openId);
        validateUserNotNull(typeUser);
        id = typeUser.getId();
        break;
   // same for the rest
```

now you have two lines of *identical code* in each case block.

```
        validateUserNotNull(typeUser);
        id = typeUser.getId();
```

You can select this two lines in one of the case blocks and invoke your IDE's *automated refactoring* `extract method`. This will replace all the occurences of the repeated identical code with a call to the new method create by this refactoring:

```
private Optional<Integer> getId(int type, String appId, String openId) {
    Integer id = null;
    switch (type) {
        case 1:
            TypeUser typeUser = userRepository.getType1User(openId);
            id = extracted(typeUser, id);
            break;
        case 2:
            TypeUser typeUser = userRepository.getType2User(openId);
            id = extracted(typeUser, id);
            break;
        case 4:
            TypeUser typeUser = userRepository.getType4UserByOpenId(openId);
            id = extracted(typeUser, id);
            break;
       // same for the rest
    }
}
private Integer extracted(TypeUser typeUser, Integer id){
    validateUserNotNull(typeUser);
    id = typeUser.getId();
    return id;
}
```

Of cause you should give the new methid a carefully chosen name but I keep the name suggested by my IDE on purpose.

Next you can use your IDE's refactoring *inline* to combine the two lines in the switch to one line:

```
    switch (type) {
        case 1:
            id = extracted(userRepository.getType1User(openId), id);
            break;
        case 2:
            id = extracted(userRepository.getType2User(openId), id);
            break;
        case 4:
            id = extracted(userRepository.getType4UserByOpenId(openId), id);
            break;
       // same for the rest
```

Obviously it is not meaningfull to pass the `null` reference stored in variable `id` to the method. Tho change that we first avoid the use of this parameter in our new method by directly returning the return value of `TypeUser::getId()`

```
private Integer extracted(TypeUser typeUser, Integer id){
    validateUserNotNull(typeUser);
    return typeUser.getId();
}
```

Then place the cursor on the method name and invoke your IDE's refactoring `change method signature`. In the upcomming dialog select the id ror in the list of parameters ad click *remove*. This removes thisparameter vrom the method declaration as well as from anny usage of that method:

```
    switch (type) {
        case 1:
            id = extracted(userRepository.getType1User(openId));
            break;
        case 2:
            id = extracted(userRepository.getType2User(openId));
            break;
        case 4:
            id = extracted(userRepository.getType4UserByOpenId(openId));
            break;
       // same for the rest


private Integer extracted(TypeUser typeUser){
    validateUserNotNull(typeUser);
    return typeUser.getId();
}
```

Since after the switch you do nothing else then returning the value of `id` you can directly return the outcome of the new method `extracted()` and get rid of the extra break line:

```
private Optional<Integer> extracted(TypeUser typeUser){
    validateUserNotNull(typeUser);
    return OptionalOf(typeUser.getId());
}

    switch (type) {
        case 1:
            return extracted(userRepository.getType1User(openId));
        case 2:
            return extracted(userRepository.getType2User(openId));
        case 4:
            return extracted(userRepository.getType4UserByOpenId(openId));
       // same for the rest
       default:
           return Optional.empty();
     }
 } // nothing more in method...
```

---

However...

To stress the good advice of [Ankit Soni](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/198213/121225) again throughout your program you should replace branching with polymorphism. To enable that your method should not return an I but a `TypeUser` object so that the rest of the code can call a method defined in the `TypeUser` *interface* not needing to know what concrete type of user actually is given.

Answer (score 0):

## Separate concerns

You mixed up concerns. You can easily see that as some repository methods are not using the "appId" parameter.

As the "appId" is bound to the "type" at any place you call the method you have to decide anyway how to get the id. So I suggest to divide the method into two methods. One with and one without the "appId".

## Ambigious return semantics

If an id could not be determined you are either returning Optional or throwing an Exception.

You should NOT distinguish between these cases in two syntactical ways. This confuses the caller because you have two handles of "Not found".

I suggest to throw different Exceptions: "Not found in Repository of type X" and "Unknown type".

## User-Interface

If you do not already have an interface with at least one method getting the "id" you should introduce it:

```
interface User {
    int getId();
    ...
}

class Type11User implements User {
    ...
}
```

## Reduce code through proper structure

As some others suggest you should introduce a map to handle retreiving the id in an abstract way.

There are some other possibilities to reduce redundancy furthermore such as passing lambdas as parameters to explicitly define differences in a general template method.

## Harmonize parameters

As only one getter (getType8User) is using a Long-Parameter you should think about changing it to a String as well and parse it to a Long within the getter. You may also consider changing all other getters to numerics (Long or Number) but I suggest them to be all of the same type.

## Code suggestion

```
private <TYPE, GETTER> Integer getIdTemplate(int type, Map<TYPE, GETTER> getterByUserType, Function<GETTER, User> getterExecutor) {

    GETTER getter = getterByUserType.get(type);

    if (getter == null) {
        throw new UnknownTypeException();
    }

    User user = getterExecutor.apply(getter);

    if (user == null) {
        throw new UserNotFoundException();
    }

    return user.getId();

}

private Integer getId(int type, String appId, String openId) {

    Map<Integer, BiFunction<String, String, User>> getterByUserType = new HashMap<>();

    getterByUserType.put(2, userRepository::getType11UserByTokenAndUID);
    getterByUserType.put(4, userRepository::getType12UserByAppIdAndOpenId);
    getterByUserType.put(5, userRepository::getType13UserByAppIdAndOpenId);

    return getIdTemplate(type, getterByUserType, f -> f.apply(appId, openId));
}

private Integer getId(int type, String openId) {

    Map<Integer, Function<String, User>> getterByUserType = new HashMap<>();

    getterByUserType.put(1, userRepository::getType1User);
    getterByUserType.put(2, userRepository::getType2User);
    getterByUserType.put(4, userRepository::getType4UserByOpenId);
    getterByUserType.put(5, userRepository::getType5UserByOpenId);
    getterByUserType.put(6, userRepository::getType6UserByOpenId);
    getterByUserType.put(8, userRepository::getType8User);

    return getIdTemplate(type, getterByUserType, f -> f.apply(openId));
}
```